# How to use third-party components in angular 5 with aot?

Tags: angular

The library includes two files (in node_modules/my-lib):

1. some-component.js
2. some-component.metadata.json

ngc creates a factory:

```
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
import * as i1 from "@angular/forms";
import * as i2 from "@angular/common";
import * as i3 from "./some-component"; // <--- wtf?
```

rollup does not find the "./some-component" file, since it is in node_modules/my-lib.

Earlier, in Angular 4, the factory was created this way:

```
import * as i0 from '@angular/core';
import * as i1 from '@angular/forms';
import * as i2 from '@angular/common';
import * as i3 from 'my-lib/some-component'; // <--- OK
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "outDir": "tmp/aot-js",
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "src / app / app.module.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "skipMetadataEmit": false,
        "strictMetadataEmit": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "tmp/**/*",
        "src/main.ts"
    ]
}
```

How to use third-party libraries now?

Comment: I do not use angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

You've to declare the path of JS component in .angular-cli.json file under "scripts" array

Comment: I do not use angular-cli